# How to subclass UITableViewController with non-optional property

Tags: ios, swift

If I setup a UITableViewController like this:

```
class FolderTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var rootFolder:String

    init(path:String) {

        rootFolder = path        
        super.init(style: .Plain)

    }
}
```

Then I get a runtime error: `fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)'`

If I add in the initializer `init(nibName:bundle:)`, then I get a compile-time error `property 'self.rootFolder' not initialized at super.init call`

... but I can't set the string in that method -- the string value is only available in my own intializer, and in fact has already been set.

Am I missing something on how this is supposed to work, or is this a bug? The only possible solution I can think of is to make the property optional.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just quickly get rid of the error you can do this:

```
var rootFolder:String = ""
```

But if you want to fully understand why you get that error then you should read this section of the Swift docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Here is also a great article by Ash Furrow on Swift Initializers:
http://ashfurrow.com/blog/swift-initializers

Comment: That's a good solution; it solves the immediate problem. But what's happening doesn't seem to follow the developer guide. The flow of code goes from (subclass initializer) -> (superclass initializer) -> (different subclass initializer). The doc's "Rule 1" says "A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass." But UITableViewController has a designated initializer that calls another designated initializer in the same class (not superclass).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "(different subclass initializer)". In your code above, the main issue is that your subclass' property `rootFolder` must be set to an initial value before the super's init can be called.

Comment: From the Swift docs: "Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state."

Comment: Also, to clarify, the reason you get the 2nd error about `init(nibName:bundle:)` is because you have specified a designated initializer in your subclass which then makes it so that your subclass does NOT inherit the superclass designated initializers: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_335

Comment: in my init method, the property **is** set before super.init() is called. But then the compiler insists that it be set **again** in init(nibName:bundle:). I can't do that, because the value of the property isn't known in that initializer, only in the first initializer.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean now. :-) When `init(nibName:bundle:)` is called you've already instantiated `rootFolder` in `init(path:String)`. I wonder if this is either a bug in the compiler or if it's on purpose to force us to set our properties either at declaration or before the super class call regardless of what else has happened before. Interesting stuff!

Comment: aus10c: from further questions on another mailing list, it appears that this is a bug and will be fixed in a future version of Swift.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I'll look forward to the fix!